# Solving series and if it's convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Is the following series convergent? If yes then what is it's value?
>   $$\text{S}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n(1+\ln^2(n))}$$

Would I use partial fractions so it would be a telescoping series and solve from there to see if it is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Have you tried an integral test?

Comment: Since ${\text d(\ln x)\over \text dx}={\text dx\over x}$ a substitution like $x=\ln n$ transforms this into $\text dx\over 1+x^2$...

Answer (score 4):

Notice that

$$\frac1{n(1+\ln^2 n)}\sim_\infty\frac1{n\ln^2n}$$
and using the integral test we get

$$\int_2^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x}=-\ln^{-1}x\Bigg|_2^\infty=\ln^{-1}2<\infty$$
so the given series is convergent by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

For every $k\geqslant0$ and every $n\geqslant1$ between $\mathrm e^k$ and $\mathrm e^{k+1}$, $n\geqslant \mathrm e^k$ and $\ln n\geqslant k$, and there are at most $\mathrm e^{k+1}$ such integers $n$ hence $$\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n(1+\ln^2n)}\leqslant\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac{\mathrm e^{k+1}}{\mathrm e^k(1+k^2)}=\mathrm e\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac1{1+k^2}\leqslant\mathrm e+\mathrm e\sum_{k\geqslant1}\frac1{k^2}.$$ Can you conclude? (This technique is called a [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).)

> If yes then what is it's value?

There is no reason to expect a closed form for the sum of this convergent series.